# Multiple && and ||?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a statement with multiple ANDS and ORS, is this possible?

This is what i currently have:

```
elseif ($a == 'promo' && strstr(ucwords($promo_name),'30% Off') && $b == 'yes')
{echo 'this is a 30% off promotion'; }
```

I am looking to echo the same message if the `$promo_name` has either '30% Off' OR 'Save 30%'.

Would I be correct with this?

```
elseif ($a == 'promo' && strstr(ucwords($promo_name),'30% Off') || 
        strstr(ucwords($promo_name),'Save 30%') && $b == 'yes')
{echo 'this is a 30% off promotion'; }
```

Im getting a little confused with what will take precedence etc. I need both `$a == 'promo'` and `$b == 'yes'` to be true at all times, with any 1 of the 2 `strstr` being true.

Any help much appreciated.

thanks

m,ike

Comment: [It is nice that we have such a good manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @Notulysses Totally agreed, kind of wish people would actually read the manual..

Comment: Parenthese to the rescue

Comment: Simply always use parantheses. Then you don't have to remember the logic of the precedence. What's the precedence here: `if ($x - $y + $z == 2)` ...

Answer (score 5):

The precedence of && is higher than ||. So you need to use some parentheses to make your statement work, as you expect:

```
elseif ($a == 'promo' && (strstr(ucwords($promo_name),'30% Off') || strstr(ucwords($promo_name),'Save 30%')) && $b == 'yes')
```

Comment: Yes, however I would recommend to make something clearer, for the sake of the future maintainer, that can be even you (OP).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
if ((($a == "a") || ($b == "b")) && ($foo == "bar")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

When I first studied boolean algebra in electronics, we were told that `and` was like a `×` and `or` like a `+`. This is true for operator precedence (`a and b or c` translates to `a × b + c` and hence `(a × b) + c`), and also helps for truth tables or complicated boolean expressions, expression development, etc.

```
a   b   a×b   a+b
0   0    0     0
0   1    0     1
1   0    0     1
1   1    1    2=1
```

This is a good mnemonic, but don't ever say that to a mathematician ;-)

So, just to be clear, `and` has higher precedence than `or` so yo need parenthesis to do what you'd like : `bool1 and (bool2 or bool3)`